# Progressive Enhancement/Graceful Degradation for HTML5 and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Can someone give some specific definitions (if there are any) for the following:

- Shims
- Fallbacks
- Polyfills

These are important topics at the moment and these particular terms are being thrown around in the blogosphere rather loosely, from what I can see. I would really like a definitive explanation of the terms and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

polyfill: A shim that mimics a future API, providing fallback functionality to older browsers.

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/

http://blog.reybango.com/2010/10/11/how-polyfills-fill-in-the-gaps-to-make-html5-and-css3-usable-today/

Comment: +1 for the links... looking through them I find a definition for Polyfill, but nowhere can I find an explanation of these other terms and how they all relate to each other.

Comment: Marked as answer... can feel a blog coming on ;-)